# Yes / No Attribute with expiration date

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I want that for a specified period, the attribute is changed from yes to no. because someone has an idea?

This is my current code:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText(‘backthere’) == “Yes”): ?>
   <span class="backthere">Wieder da</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: i can't understand if yes it should display Wieder da Right

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: $custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
$store_vies_val = $custom->getAttributeText('backthere');
if (($store_vies_val == 'Yes'){?>
<span class="backthere">Wieder da</span><?php
}

Comment: Ok and where is the expiration date?

Comment: I guess what you are asking is to have 2 attributes here, one that holds value of Yes/No, and one that holds date on the basis of which you will decide expiration. Try configuring your code with that in mind and you might get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thank you guys. I have solved it. 
Here is my solution:

```
<?php
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $wiederdaTo =  substr($_product->getData('wiederdadatum'),0,10);

    if (($now<=$wiederdaTo))
{?>
<span class="wiederda">Wieder da</span>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating attributes with proper validation.
Refer `new from` and `new to` attributes or special price from and to attributes.
Create date attribute and use that in a cron or just put a condition while rendering.